# Difference between Level 1 Oplock and Filter Oplock

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, server-message-block, cifs

As I know, there are 4 types of Opportunistic Locks: Level 1, Level 2, Filter, and Batch. For me, Level 1, Level 2 and Batch Oplock are not so difficult to understand, but I still don't understand Filter Oplock, which case it is used and what are differences between Level 1 Oplock and Filter Oplock